# Reuse credentials if same data in same security environment

Tags: passwords, defense

We're managing a shared hosting environment of Wordpress websites on a web server.

Each site has its own database password and FTP password, both are randomly generated and stored in AWS ParameterStore (not secrets manager for cost reasons)

We are now adding a caching database.

It seems we should be able to re-use database credentials to authenticate against the caching database, as it contains a subset of the relational database and runs in the same network environment/ same set of web servers.

Is there any reason to generate a 3rd password for this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to generate a third password for this functionality. You can re-use the database credentials to authenticate against the caching database.

It seems we should be able to re-use database credentials to authenticate against the caching database, as it contains a subset of the relational database and runs in the same network environment/ same set of web servers- this explains it all, is never a good idea to go against documentations when adding new features to something that will be on the open for hackers

Comment: be interested to hear the opinion of the downvoter